# PHP calling python not working

Tags: php, python, raspberry-pi

I'm having issues getting a python script to run through PHP.  I can run my python script manually with no problems, but cannot run it through PHP.  I am calling the PHP script from a web page that I want to execute a python script.  I have searched all over to try and figure this out, but I can not manage to get it to work.  I have tried exec(), system(), shell_exec(), etc. to run the script without success.  I have also done a chmod +x on the python script.  I have tried things like

```
<?php 
exec('/usr/bin/python /root/Desktop/ledtest.py');
?>
```

Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Edit:
I'm trying to give more information but sadly I can't.  I just came into this company as an intern and I'm trying to pick up where the previous intern left off (it's a huge mess and no one seems to know whats going on here).  Sorry for the lack of information

Comment: So what exactly happens when you try to run the script?

Comment: Can you tell us what web server is running? Apache, nginx, lighttpd, etc? When you say "but cannot run it through PHP" what do you mean? Do you mean it doesn't run the script when you visit the web page? Or do you mean you are calling the script directly somehow (command line)?

Answer (score 0):

What error message you are getting as PHP has some kind of limit, like 30sec, you may easily find from calling phpinfo() and searching for max_execution_time in the output. it's possible to change this from the script to a higher value, if you need, using ini_set('max_execution_time', 1200);, and you may get another details about max_execution_time from this question: stackoverflow.com/questions/4220413/…

Additionally,

Whatever error python is raising would be going to the child's stderr. Try either telling php to read from stderr, or (in python) do this:

import sys
sys.stderr = sys.stdout

Comment: I'm not getting an error from PHP or python at all.  This is why I am so confused.  Everything appears to be working fine, but it isn't

Answer (score 0):

To start with, you should know that providing more specific details (steps to reproduce errors, actual error messages, web server software and version, etc) will yield better answers.

The problem is most likely related to the permissions of your web server. When you test the code, you are likely calling PHP manually (e.g. `php myscript.php`) or possibly just calling the python directly.

First, check what user the web server runs under. For example, apache may run as "apache", "nobody", or "www-data" depending on your config. Then verify that that user has permission to execute your python script. This may be possible through an ExecCGI type configuration in your web server settings. Alternately you may decide to add sudo rights to execute the script, and then include "sudo" in your php exec.

**NOTE**: *It is a very bad idea* to give general sudo access to a web server. If you do this, make sure you give access only to the one script, and make sure that your script does not have the potential to be a security hole.

Probably the best solution would be to have your web server execute the Python directly using extensions, plugins, modules, or whatever your particular server uses to execute CGI scripts.